# this is sql table tbl_message distinct records by user_id but last id display mins DESC record form id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

this is sql table  tbl_message distinct records by user_id but last id display mins DESC record form id

```
+-----------------------+
|id | user_id | message |
+---+---------+---------+
| 1 |    1    |  test   |
| 2 |    2    | testing |
| 3 |    1    |  heloo  |
| 4 |    3    |    hi   |
| 5 |    3    |  hello  |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: and the question is....

Comment: What is your question? What output you want?

Comment: question is select query in my sql list a record.

Comment: So you want a select query?

Comment: yes select query distinct records by user_id but last id display mins DESC record form id

Comment: So you want to select one message per user_id and the message should by the one with maximal id? That's what you are asking?

Comment: select unique user id and last message will display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what are you looking for

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.*
FROM 
    `messages` `t1`
        INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    MAX(`id`) as `latest`,
                    `user_id`
                FROM
                    `messages`
                GROUP BY
                    `user_id`) `t2`
        ON
            `t1`.`user_id` = `t2`.`user_id` AND
            `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`latest`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need latest insterted user_id without duplication then you should be use this query

`SELECT t2.id,t2.message,t2.user_id 
 FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT user_id,message,id FROM msg ORDER BY user_id)t2 
,msg t1 GROUP BY user_id;`

Comment: This also works fine. It is hard to say which request is faster. Maybe Prashant Kyada should compare performance of both queries on at aleast 100k records.

Comment: @sajushko you are right :).